# How to return zero on empty filter in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this seeming simple problem.

I've made the following filter to find a certain type of sales in april of 2018:

- The price is in column X
- A Date string is in column A
- the type of sold product is in colomn AF

I would like to sum column X for sales type 1

```
=SUM(filter('SALES'!X:X;YEAR('SALES'!A:A) =2018; MONTH('SALES'!A:A) = 4;'SALES'!AF:AF=1))
```

All works great if something has been sold, but if nothing of this type has been sold this gives an "#N/B" (in dutch).

I tried:

```
=if(countifs(YEAR('SALES'!A:A); "=2018"; MONTH('SALES'!A:A); "=4";'SALES'!AF:AF; "=1"; >0; the filter; 0)))
```

but it doesn't work. countifs errors: matrixarguments for countifs have different sizes (translated from Dutch :))

How do I handle a filter that ends up with zero rows? I just want a 0 in that case.

Hope any of you can help. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm in doubt whether I should feel ashamed for not knowing this function or happy that you just taught me :)! The result is a happiness! Thank you! Works like a charm